# How to specify big marks separator in flextable object without using column names?

Tags: r, printf, flextable

**Context:** I am creating .docx table using awesome package `flextable`. This package has a function to format numbers in the final output: `set_formatter_type()`. This function, if i understand correctly, requires a character input that can be used by `sprintf()`. I was able to acheive the expected output using `set_formatter()` but it required to explicitely name each column and I can not do that with my real table.

**Problem:** I can not find how to add big marks (e.g. thousand separator) using `sprintf()` synthax that works with `flextable::set_formatter_type()`.

It is possible to acheive the right formatting using `formatC()` but this function does not work with `flextable::set_formatter_type()`

```
formatC(x = signif(1715235456.5684, 3), big.mark = " ", digits = 0, format = "f")
[1] "1 720 000 000"
```

Using `sprintf()` I was able to acheive:

```
 sprintf("%.0f", signif(1715235456.5684, 3))
[1] "1720000000"
```

**Reproducible example:**

```
df <- flextable::flextable(iris[1:3]*1000)
flextable::set_formatter_type(df, fmt_double = "%.0f") # works fine but I can't get big mark separator
flextable::set_formatter_type(df, fmt_double = function(x) formatC(x, digits = 0, big.mark = " ")) # does not work (error)
flextable::set_formatter(df, Sepal.Length = function(x) formatC(x, digits = 0, big.mark = " ", format = "f")) # works but I would like not to have to name each column from my real life dataframe...
```

**Expected output:**

```
flextable::set_formatter(df, 
                         Sepal.Length = function(x) formatC(x, digits = 0, big.mark = " ", format = "f"),
                         Sepal.Width = function(x) formatC(x, digits = 0, big.mark = " ", format = "f"),
                         Petal.Lenght = function(x) formatC(x, digits = 0, big.mark = " ", format = "f"))
```

Comment: Maybe this could help <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49456979/formatting-multiple-columns-with-flextable-r-package>.  I think this link <https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/blob/master/R/formatters.R#L74> from the mentioned site could be of your interest.

Comment: Many thanks for the links, I was able to acheive the wanted result with it.

Comment: Perfect. You could answer your question in order to help other users in the same situation!

Comment: You can use function `colformat_double` for that. See https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/cell-content-1.html#simple-formatting-of-cell-content and maybe that example: https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-gallery/gallery/2021-04-02-custom-cell-content/

Comment: @DavidGohel thanks, I did not know about the `colformat_double()` function (even after a lot of reasearch I was not able to find it). Many thanks for your amazing package!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @TarJae and @DavidGohel comments, here is how the problem can be solved using `flextable::colformat_double()` function as described here: https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/blob/master/R/formatters.R#L135

Up to date information can be found here: https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/cell-content-1.html#simple-formatting-of-cell-content

```
df <- flextable::flextable(iris[1:3]*1000)

flextable::colformat_double(df, big.mark = " ", digits = 0)
```

The output:

[image]

Credits: [Formatting multiple columns with flextable r package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49456979/formatting-multiple-columns-with-flextable-r-package)

Comment: Perfect. Good to see that you were able to solve it!

Comment: Well I feel a little bit idiot not to have found it after 2 hours of research... but I am glad you and David commented on it! Many many thanks!

Comment: Would you mind updating the link you provided to a link to the documentation? https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/cell-content-1.html#simple-formatting-of-cell-content Because the one you are using are not pointing to the solution but to an old solution and also because linking to sources that can change over time will probably make your link irrelevant later